# How to plot a parabola by getting its parameters from the gui using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-guide

I've tried to do it like this:

I've found this https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-draw-a-parabola-in-MATLAB and tried to use it like that:

```
a=str2double(get(handles.InputA,'string'));
b=str2double(get(handles.InputB,'string'));
c=str2double(get(handles.InputC,'string'));
xLine=[(-b)/2*a-5:0.01:(-b)/2*a+5];
yToPlot= a*x.^2 + b.x+c;
plot(xLine,yToPlot);
```

but I keep getting errors...any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the variable `xLine`, but use the variable `x` in `yToPlot`. That's why you get an error saying `x` is not defined. Also in `yToPlot` you have `b.x`. MATLAB then thinks that `b` is a struct and that you want to access the field named `x` of `b`. Since `b` is not a struct, and doesn't have a field `x`, you'll get the error 'Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.'. If you fix these two, it should work, according to the code you've given:

```
xLine=[(-b)/2*a-5:0.01:(-b)/2*a+5];
yToPlot= a*xLine.^2 + b*xLine+c;
plot(xLine,yToPlot);
```